# How to copy multiple files from resource folder to document directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to copy multiple files(with .vot files) from my app to document directory path.

Here I am going to add some files in my project and this files need to be copied in document directory folder.

For Example ,

I have files like

1) One.vot

2) Two.vot

How do I copy this .vot files in document directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString* directoryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/Files", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex: 0]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:NO error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *FilesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"path1",@"path2"]];//add file Paths To FilesArray    
    for(int i=0;i<[FilesArray count];i++)
    {
        NSString *str=[directoryPath copy];
        str=[str stringByAppendingPathExtension:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"File %i",i+1]];
        NSData *FileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[FilesArray objectAtIndex:i]]; 
        [FileData writeToFile:str atomically:NO];
        [str release];
    }
```

Comment: Hey my files contain different name, So how can I use ` str=[str stringByAppendingPathExtension:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"File %i",i+1]];
`